# Sbt download repository Forbidden

Tags: scala, sbt, deb

Edit: Looks like this has been resolved.  Links are working again.

#

I am unable to download sbt using the links provided on the site- I keep getting a forbidden error:

The two links from the sbt download website aren't working- http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html.

and the debian package isn't working either:

https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/Release

Are there any other ways to get the debian packages for SBT?

Thanks

Comment: I believe there's an issue between the sbt maintainers and bintray.  I tried to post a reply to the release posting for sbt 13.15 on sbt-dev google group.  But by reply is awaiting moderation. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sbt-dev/aR9hEppbaNs

Comment: problem is being worked on: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links were posted in the github issue for this:
https://downloads.typesafe.com/sbt/0.13.15/sbt-0.13.15.tgz
https://downloads.typesafe.com/sbt/0.13.15/sbt-0.13.15.zip

Answer (score 3):

The real solution is here https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/449/817884851

Just do the following in your script:

`rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list`

`sudo apt-get update`